# Change the directory that pytest uses for testing, but not output location

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have this kind of directory structure:

```
repo/
├── src/
|   ├── assets
|   |   └── wordlist.txt
|   └── main.py
└── tests
     └── test_cases.py
```

And I want to test a class in the main.py file. That classes reads from a word list in the assets directory. But when i run the test from the tests directory it uses that directory as the starting point so when init. the class it can't find the word list. And I get the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: assets/wordlist.txt` .

So how do I change the directory pytest usages for the test but still keep the output in the tests folder. I tried to use the `pytest.ini` file and change the `pythonpath = . src` but that just seems to move the output to the repo directory and keeps the file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, but not by changing the the setting for pytest. But by changing my input path, so instead of hardcoding it in like `assets/wordlists.txt`. I changed it to:

```
directory_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
new_path = os.path.join(directory_path, "assets/English_5words.txt")
```

Comment: This is a good idea generally - this would have stopped working if you had pip installed it too. Now your module can be executed from any location :)